# Selecting events in Fullcalendar using Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, contains

I am using Fullcalendar to retrieve a Google Calendar of mine and post it in a website - this way I can access the CSS of what otherwise would be an iframe.

I would like to select certain events in the calendar and give them a 'type event' background: red for meetings, blue for lunches, etc. (just an example). As an 'easy' way to do this, I would write a JavaScript function using jQuery that selects all elements with a certain innerHTML. This is the selecting bit:

```
$("span:contains('meeting')")
```

But it's not working for those elements inside of the calendar. It selects all other suitable elements outside the said table, but not inside. ¿Any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can easily set background color to different type of events using color attribute in FullCalendar.

for example:

your events are like

```
events: [                                   
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false,
                    backgroundColor: '#fff000'  // your color
                } ]
```

from your Json event you can set color to your events using backgroundColor property

see -->  http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

Comment: Sure, but my events come from the Google Calendar API. There is no such Json.